# resolve dependency inside quartz job

Tags: c#, quartz.net

```
public class SyncJob : IJob
{
    var typeId = GetType();

    ISync sync = ResolveDependencyBasedOnTypeId();//This function will resolve dependency.
}

public interface ISync{}

public class Sync1 : ISync{}

public class Sync2 : ISync{}
```

I do have the above situation.

I use Unity to configure and resolve dependency.

My question is how my quartz job will know about configured dependencies.

Quartz job and Quartz scheduler are 2 different projects.

Is JobData a good option to pass the unity object to quartz job?

Comment: _Is JobData a good option to pass the unity object to quartz job?_ No, Unity is a DI Tool, DI is the execution of IOC and IOC is the Idea to inject all necessary dependencies through the constructor during the creation of the object. In your case, just inject a factory to resolve the `ISync` you need.

Comment: I dont want to control the object creation. if i create a factory then i will have to create objects from factory. I don't want that. I want to use the power of DI. Unity should take care of object creation and manage the object scope.